# UIToolbar Slide Out From Under UITabBar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, interface-builder

I have an application that requires synchronization and I wanted to inform the user of the synchronization by sliding up a UIToolbar from underneath a UITabBar. I currently have:

```
// AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options
{
    ...
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:self.syncToolbar];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar sendSubviewToBack:self.syncToolbar];
    ...
}
```

However, the UITabBar appears to be transparent (as the tool bar shows even when it is behind). Any way I can get the UIToolbar to look like it is sliding up from underneath the UITabbar? Thnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
[self.tabBarController.view insertSubview:self.syncToolbar belowSubview:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

That should position your sync view where you want it.